# How to change startup file index.html to other html file in phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-cli

How to change startup file index.html to other html file in phonegap. I change the content src="login.html"  in config.xml file but it won't work. It always load the index.html file. please help. Thanx in advanced.

> config.xml

```
<content src="login.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<access origin="" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Could you share the entire config file ?

Comment: `    <content src="login.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" /> <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>`

Comment: I also change all index.html path  reference to login.html in all file but still it won't work. please tell me how could I change the path to login page when the app open.

Comment: Check config at `/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml` to see if your config is updated. Are you trying this by hot-reloading? I don't think it will update config then.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to start to another page than index.html (wouldn't it be easier to rename your login.html to index.html?)

Anyway, what you could do is have a minimal index.html file that redirects to login.html by adding a script tag like this :

```
   <script>
        window.location = './login.html';
    </script>
```

That's something I use in my apps because cordova may refuse to start the app if index.html takes too long to start.

Comment: but it still load index.html first and the redirect to login.html. and that takes more time.

Comment: I don't think few ms should be a issue. Especially after you will add native loader overlay. But now what happens if user is logged in? You will need to redirect him to index ?

Comment: actually I want my first page as login page as my startup page then the index page is load. but whenever I open my app it always open index page first then redirect to login page when I'm using window.replace('login.html) or window.location='login.html'. Is there any way that I can change the Load page index.html to custom page html.